# Sorting error for Time row value in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, sorting, pivot-table

I've encountered an issue with a pivot table that I occasionally use, though I don't update. Specifically there are three Row Fields applied Year, Day (d-mon format), and then Transaction Date/Time (which displays only the hour component of the value). The pivot table is supposed to sort by Year, then Day, then Hour. The first two sorts work fine, but the third has started to sort the Hour values as text rather than numbers, so it's ordered 1 AM, 1 PM, 10 AM, 10 PM, etc. I've checked and there are no non-time values in the source field, the column of the pivot table itself is still set to a Time format type, and there are no filters applied to the field.

At this point I'm not sure what else to look for. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: The file is in Sharepoint so I tried taking the prior version (there are only two), dropping in the latest data from the current version, and refreshing the pivot table. The error dutifully appeared. So it does appear to be a data issue, but I can't imagine what's causing the issue. As stated above, I already checked that the values were Dates, specifically I used `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(C2, "m/d/yyyy h:mm"))), "", 1)` and checked that all rows returned as blanks.

Something that may be causing issues is how the Year and Day fields come about. Specifically, there are no such fields in the Source Data, they are calculated Row Fields based on the one Transaction Date/Time column. I'm not even sure how this was done (to my knowledge calculated fields can only be columns) so I can't really look into if it may be causing the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem and found no good way around it in Excel.  What I ended up doing (that worked for me) is to extract the 24hour "hour value" from a date field using `=VALUE(TEXT(A2,"h"))` (where A2 contains the time/date code I'm looking for).  I then used the date code itself (Column A in this example) as the first Row Label (first grouped item) then added the "hour value" as a secondary Row Label/Group.  This allows leveraging the Pivot Table sort/group function naturally and then adds the detail in the order I want.
I did not solve the problem for 12 hour display with AM/PM as this was good enough for my needs.